# Uncaught Error: Class 'MobileDetect' not found

Tags: php, class

So I'm working on this aspect of a PHP App where I want to use retrieve user's device info and more using the ***Mobile Detect*** library. I've everything set. However, I still get the ***Uncaught Error: Class 'MobileDetect' not found*** error. Maybe I'm making a mistake somewhere. Help me out, Guys. I don't know what I'm doing wrong.

The code below is from the page where I include the MobileDetect class

```
require_once 'MobileDetect.php';
    
$detect = new MobileDetect();
```

I've added a screenshot of the full error i get from the network console below:

***Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'MobileDetect' not found in /home/sites/9b/c/c08fc3c530/public_html/newproject12/auth/config/functions.inc.php:19 Stack trace: #0 /home/sites/9b/c/c08fc3c530/public_html/newproject12/auth/controllers/loginController.php(41): logUserLogin('james.kuma1995@...') #1 {main} thrown in /home/sites/9b/c/c08fc3c530/public_html/newproject12/auth/config/functions.inc.php on line 19***

[SCREENSHOT OF FULL ERROR FROM NETWORK CONSOLE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GGnLi.png)

Comment: Impossible to answer without seeing the contents of `MobileDetect.php`

Comment: If it comes from [this library](https://github.com/serbanghita/Mobile-Detect), I suggest you take a closer look at the documentation; the class is namespaced

Comment: @Phil Hey man I think you got a point. So here's the link to the class [link](https://github.com/serbanghita/Mobile-Detect/blob/3.74.x/src/MobileDetect.php)

Comment: @Phil ... Here's the beginning code for the class `namespace Detection;

use BadMethodCallException;`

Comment: Did you look at the example in the README? It literally has the solution... `$detect = new \Detection\MobileDetect;`

Comment: @Phil You mean this line `$detect = new \Detection\MobileDetect;
$deviceType = ($detect->isMobile() ? ($detect->isTablet() ? 'tablet' : 'phone') : 'computer');` ??? You saying I add to the line? If yes, Where do I add it then?

Comment: Where you have `$detect = new MobileDetect();` you need `$detect = new \Detection\MobileDetect();`. That's it, that's the whole problem solved. This can be closed as a typo

Answer (score -1):

If you are using the latest version ([3.74.0](https://github.com/serbanghita/Mobile-Detect/releases/tag/3.74.0)), you need to write:

```
require_once "src/Mobile_Detect.php";
```

At first line, and then:

```
$detect = new \Detection\MobileDetect;
$deviceType = ($detect->isMobile() ? ($detect->isTablet() ? 'tablet' : 'phone') : 'computer');
```

Comment: OP clearly doesn't need the `src/` prefix and where did that second `$deviceType` line come from? It's not in their code at all

Comment: @Phil src is from folder tree of the zip downloaded, deviceType is from official example of github

Comment: OP's require line seems to work fine so they obviously don't have the `src` directory

Comment: He can try by downloading the latest version that works with src directory.